# What is the difference between defining the index as a primary key or in the CREATE INDEX clause?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, ddl

I am testing a query with a table of 500 million records.
The field ID_COMPANY only has value 1 (500 millon records).

The SQL is defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE "BIDATA"."CSC_CUSTOMER_PREPAID_BALANCE" 
(   "ID_COMPANY" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
    "SEQUENTIAL_MOV" NUMBER(10,0),
    "ID_PAYMENT" NUMBER(10,0)
CONSTRAINT "PK_CSC_CUSTOMER_PREPAID_BAL" PRIMARY KEY ("ID_COMPANY", "SEQUENTIAL_MOV")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS NOLOGGING 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "BIDATA_DATOS"  ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 0 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "BIDATA_DATOS" ;
```

CREATE INDEX clause for the ID_PAYMENT field for example

```
CREATE INDEX "BIDATA"."IDX_ID_PAYMENT" ON "BIDATA"."CSC_CUSTOMER_PREPAID_BALANCE" ("ID_PAYMENT") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "BIDATA_DATOS" ;
```

The problem that I have, that when launching a query as defined, it seems that it does not detect the index ID_COMPANY and it takes more than 15 minutes to show results, but if in the query in the WHERE clause I add ID_COMPANY = '1', it shows the results in less than 10 seconds.

Should I delete the index ID_COMPANY and define it as CREATE INDEX?
Why does that time difference occur?

SQL query takes> 10 minutes.

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*)
FROM
  CSC_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT,
  CSC_CUSTOMER_PREPAID_BALANCE
WHERE

  AND  ( CSC_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ID_ACCOUNT(+)=CSC_CUSTOMER_PREPAID_BALANCE.ID_ACCOUNT AND CSC_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ID_COMPANY(+)=CSC_CUSTOMER_PREPAID_BALANCE.ID_COMPANY  )
  AND  ( CSC_CUSTOMER_PREPAID_BALANCE.ID_ACCOUNT (+)=CSC_RECHARGE_MOBILE.ID_ACCOUNT AND CSC_CUSTOMER_PREPAID_BALANCE.SEQUENTIAL_MOV(+)=CSC_RECHARGE_MOBILE.SEQUENTIAL_MOV  )
```

SQL query takes < 10 seconds.

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*)
FROM

  CSC_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT,
  CSC_CUSTOMER_PREPAID_BALANCE
WHERE

  AND  ( CSC_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ID_ACCOUNT(+)=CSC_CUSTOMER_PREPAID_BALANCE.ID_ACCOUNT AND CSC_CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT.ID_COMPANY(+)=CSC_CUSTOMER_PREPAID_BALANCE.ID_COMPANY  )
  AND  ( CSC_CUSTOMER_PREPAID_BALANCE.ID_ACCOUNT (+)=CSC_RECHARGE_MOBILE.ID_ACCOUNT AND CSC_CUSTOMER_PREPAID_BALANCE.SEQUENTIAL_MOV(+)=CSC_RECHARGE_MOBILE.SEQUENTIAL_MOV  )
  AND  CSC_CUSTOMER_PREPAID_BALANCE.ID_COMPANY = '1'
```

QUERY execution plan> 10 minutes

[Execution plan Query > 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnVjw.png)

[Execution plan Query < 10 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3MHO.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Your query is (probably) semantically wrong without the `ID_COMPANY` in the where clause, since the schema assumes there can be more than one.

Comment: Could you add in your query, it appears to be as simple as index fields vs predicates in terms of index usage or table scan, query will help clarify.

Comment: In the table there is only one ID_COMPANY = 1.
I have added an example query, the one that takes less than 10 seconds I have only included in the WHERE clause ID_COMPANY = '1', I do not understand why adding that instruction the query shows records quickly.

Comment: What are the execution plans for both queries? Please edit your question to add both in.

Comment: I've add the execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can infer from your question, you seem to misinterpret the indexing rules for a table. Ideally you don't create an index for the primary key, rather it is the other way around. i.e. when you create a table with a primary key it(primary key) by default is considered as a clustered index by the sql agent and created/stored accordingly. 
More on Indexing and Index types [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/clustered-and-nonclustered-indexes-described?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The question is tagged Oracle. Primary key indexes in Oracle are not "clustered indexes" (closest thing in Oracle are IOTs), they're plain unique indexes.